# Action Controller: Exception - ID not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, exception

I am slowly getting the hang of Rails and thanks to a few people I now have a basic grasp of the database relations and associations etc. You can see my previous questions here: [Rails database relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714621/rails-database-relationships)

I have setup my applications models with all of the necessary has_one and has_many :through etc. but when I go to add a kase and choose from a company from the drop down list - it doesnt seem to be assigning the company ID to the kase.

You can see a video of the the application and error here: http://screenr.com/BHC

You can see a full breakdown of the application and relevant source code at the Git repo here: http://github.com/dannyweb/surveycontrol

If anyone could shed some light on my mistake I would be appreciate it very much!

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have setup your Kase and Company models as a one-to-one relationship (see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html). This is probably not what you intended. Maybe if you could explain your intended relationship I could tell you where your mistake is?

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kases
  has_many :people
end

class Kase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company    # foreign key: company_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :people    # foreign key in join table
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :kases    # foreign key in join table
end
```

Relevant parts shown only. This should be a step in the right direction. You will need a join table for the many-to-many relationship, or alternatively, to model it using "has_many :through". Depends on whether you need to store other properties on the join. See link above for details.

Comment: Hi Jakob, 

Basically it needs to be as follows:

A case would have only one company, but a company will have many cases. A company would have many people, and each person can be linked to a case, through the company.

Does that makes sense?

Thanks,

Danny

Comment: Most of it makes sense :) Companies have many cases and people, that's clear. I'm not sure what you mean by linking a person to a case "through the company"?

Comment: Basically if we add a case, we would choose a company and then we would want a list of people within that company to choose from.

Thanks,

Danny

Comment: OK, that's a many-to-many relationship as I understand what you're saying. One case could have many people, and one person could work on many cases. I'll add to my example.

Comment: ok, I have made the changes to the models, but I still seem to be getting the same error. I have pushed the changes to the Github repo linked to above.

Comment: Hi Jakob, I have had a read of the link above but I am still struggling to get my head around it. I have a party model for the link tables which has the following: http://pastie.org/937787

Am I on the right path? If so, what next?

Comment: Sorry, the join table needs to be named "kases_people" for rails to pick it up automatically

Comment: If I am following the other answer of not having the has_and_belongs_to_many do I still need the kases_people?

Comment: No, but do note that in the other example, any given person can only be assigned to one case. If that is how you wanted it, then my assumption about many-to-many was incorrect.

Comment: ahh, I missed that completely!

I guess I need to start again then and use your example. When you said to add the join table called kases_people, I have a model called partied as noted above. Should that table have a column called kases_people?

Comment: this `parties` table should be named `kases_people`.

Comment: OK, I have renamed the table kases_people. I can get the cases working, if I add a case it will show the company I chose when I view it (show.html.erb) - but the person show won't display the company I chose when creating the record. Any ideas?

Comment: That's a lot of questions for one thread. I think you should try to isolate one problem at a time, and put each in a separate question here on SO, preferably getting your model setup correctly first (you can use IRB to validate that your model works as expected)

Comment: ok, I'm as new to Stack Overflow as I am to Rails. Appreciate your advice!

Answer (score 1):

I believe It should be

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :people
   has_many :kases
end

class Kase < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :company
   belongs_to :person
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :company
   has_one :kase
end
```

In your view (`app/views/kases/new.html.erb`) you have

```
<li>Company Select<span><%= f.select :company_id, Company.all %></span></li>
```

Try changing the select part to

```
<%= f.select :company_id, Company.all.collect {|m| [m.name, m.id]} %>
```

**Suggestion**

I also notice that you have four methods in your controller to find Kases by status. You can do this in your model, using `named_scope`. It's like this:

```
named_scope :active, :conditions => {:kase_status => 'Archived'}
```

And then, wherever you need to show only active Kases, you call `Kase.active`. The same for the other status.

Comment: ok, I have made the changes to the models, but I still seem to be getting the same error. I have pushed the changes to the Github repo linked to above.

Comment: That changes the drop down list's content to "<option value="3">DannyWeb Limited </option>, but still returns the same error message. I did change the name part to companyname to match the column in the company database. Is that right?

Comment: Hmm, same problem - would you be interested in helping me work this out and charging me for your time?

I just cannot work it out!

Comment: You have this line in your controller, right `@company = Company.find(params[:company_id])` ? You have no `params[:company_id]`, but `params[:kase][:company_id]`.

Comment: ahh, ok thats removed the error message.

What would the code be to show the company name assigned to the kase?

Comment: How do I now list all people associated under a company when I create a new case?

Comment: That's another question... I believe you should ask it separately :] Anyway, I'll think and try to answer that.

Comment: ok, but within this question (I think that's ok) should I be able to use the same code <%=h @kperson.company.companyname %> to display the listed under company?